# How to config eclipse debug to follow classes-(php files) used?

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

if you want to follow the classes loaded (to be more specific php classes) from a debug method, what is the way to do that.

I use Xdebug and lets say we have the following example:

One html file with a form inside it and one php file referenced by the previous .

How to config XDEBUG to automatically (without manual inserting of breakpoints) stop add every class(php file referenced-used). So in our case to stop on the first line of the php file without setting a breakpoint there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use eclipse for PHP, but in menu, there is Run -> Add class load breakpoint and then you specify class filter and it works for Java, so I suppose there will be something similar for PHP.